# Create table by pre-specified frequencies

Tags: r, matrix, combinatorics

I have large R matrix with 1,000 rows and 4 attributes and 4 levels each attribute such that:

```
  Row    A   B   C   D
   1     1   3   4   2
   2     2   1   3   4
   3     1   2   4   3
   ...   ...
  1000   3   4   1   2
```

I want to create a new table by pre-specified proportions such that level 1 of attribute A appears 25% of the time, level 2 50%, level 3 10% and level 4 15% of the time. The table can be of a smaller size than 1,000 rows and rows have to be uniques.

```
 proportions <- c(0.25,0.5,0.1,0.15)
```

I know it's kind of a basic question but I have broken my head for two hours and haven't found anything on Stack Overflow nor internet.

**UPDATE**

I want to keep the same combinations within rows. So I want to create a new table with the proportions given but using the table, thus the combinations, that I already have.

Answer (score -1):

You can create your set with the proportions you want then "reshuffle".

```
A <- c(rep(1,250), rep(2,500), rep(3,100), rep(4,150))
B <- sample(A, 1000)
```

EDIT:
it's not entirely cleat what the OP wants.

if you want the same exact table randomized you can try

```
df_new <- df[sample(1:nrow(df), nrow(df)),]
```

to get the same exact proportions you are restricted to a number of observation so that all the new counts are divisible by the old counts
in order to get the proportions of each unique row you can try :

```
# simulating the table
a <- c(rep(1,250), rep(2,500), rep(3,100), rep(4,150))
b <- sample(a, 4000, replace = T)

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(b, ncol = 4))

names(df) <- c('a','b','c','d')

# getting the proportions 
z <- aggregate(row.names(df), list(df$a, df$b, df$c, df$d), function(x) freq = length(x))
```

Comment: I need the same exact combinations that I already have. So creating them from the table I have keeping the combinations between columns, I don't need a new table from scratch.

Comment: The point is that currently level proportions within attributes are balanced, so they all have the same proportions, and I want them to be unbalanced but keeping the same combination.

Comment: you can use the latter part of my answer to get the unique combinations and then recreate the set using the same combinations but different proportions.